# How to Query Document Created Today Using MongoDB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid for my simple Rails 3.x app. I have this model:

```
class Report

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

end
```

I want to get all Report created today using my current timezone which is +08:00. I tried using this snippet:

```
Report.where(:created_at => DateTime.now.at_beginning_of_day.utc..Time.now.utc).to_a
```

However, when I trigger:

```
DateTime.now.at_beginning_of_day.utc
```

It gets the date yesterday and the timezone is +00:00

Comment: Why do you call `utc` if you want current timezone?

Comment: Try this `Time.now.utc.beginning_of_day`.

Comment: @Sergio The data from created is '2012-06-15 09:47:35 UTC'.

Comment: did u resolve this?I am also in need of answer

Comment: @PraveenSinghYadav Check your server's system date/time. If you don't have control on your server, you may want to specify the Timezone on your query.

Comment: @Ben I got the answer [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464886/query-mongodb-to-return-documents-created-today/21466970?noredirect=1#21466970)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be calling `Report.where(:created_at.gt => ...` to get all reports created since the beginning of the day.