# Query mongodb to return documents created today

Tags: mongodb, nosql

how can I write filter which results docs created today.I know ObjectId has timestamp. 
I tried this :

```
db.doc.find({_id : { $gte : ObjectId().getTimestamp().getTime() }}
```

Can I write

```
db.doc.find({'_id.getTimestamp().getTime()' : { $gte : ObjectId().getTimestamp().getTime() }}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following (based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749971/can-i-query-mongodb-objectid-by-date)). This returns all documents created since the given date. So it covers todays entries as well.

```
db.doc.find({_id : { $gt : ObjectId(Math.floor(new Date('2014/01/30')/1000).toString(16)+"0000000000000000") }})
```

If you don't like to enter the date as string, you can create it via Objects, but it gets a little bit ugly:

```
db.doc.find({_id : { $gt : ObjectId(Math.floor(new Date(new Date().getFullYear()+'/'+(new Date().getMonth()+1)+'/'+new Date().getDate())/1000).toString(16)+"0000000000000000") }})
```

Comment: Thanks I used this,It worked for me db.sale.aggregate({ $match :{ firm :ObjectId("52e56c009dbc794999ea5c3d") }  }, {$project : {day : {$dayOfMonth : '$date'},items :1,patient :1}}, {$match : {day: {$gte : new Date().getDate()}}}, {$unwind : "$items"}, {$group :{_id:"$_id"  ,count :{$sum:1},patient:"$patient"} })

Answer (score 0):

use this query, you can easily get the document created today
but we have a problem,
The day(24h) starts now and ends at tomorrow this time

```js
    let dateStart = new Date()
    let dateEnd = new Date()
    dateStart.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)
    dateEnd.setUTCDate(23,59,59,999)
    db.doc.find({$and:[{appointmentDate:{$gt: dateStart}},{appointmentDate:{$lt: dateEnd}}]})
```